# Sharepoint Forms from Custom Lists

Tags: sharepoint

I created a Custom SharePoint List with a custom work flow. Basically the list does the following:

1. Group A initiates the list, fills in all the information
2. Group A will check a box based on a Y/N question, the driver of the work flow is if the Y/N question is answered with an Y, the Group B will get a task assigned and an email notification will go to Group B to continue the work flow.
3. Group B will fill out information and check Y/N question, if answer is returned Y it will go to Group C via the same method as above.

What I need is as the form goes from one group to the next how can I make sure that Group C doesn't see the responses from Group B? How do I write this into the workflow?

Comment: Set item permissions on each update.

Answer (score 1):

We use a custom form framework (called ShockOut SPForms) that allows us to display content based on group membership.  We make the form as a .aspx file in the site (using sharepoint designer).  [Click here](https://github.com/jbonfardeci/ShockoutForms) to check out the framework.  Using this custom framework allows us to make very customized forms by using some html and a little javascript.

You asked how to write the access control into the workflow, so my answer may not be right on target.  However, the workflow does not control access to the list data.

Column level permissions are not included in SharePoint to my knowledge.  You may need to split the information into separate lists to enable access control.

Using a custom form and some queries to the REST or SOAP api, you could accomplish your result.  (Note: this last suggestion is for SharePoint experts).